# How to include irdadump into Yocto (Poky) irda-utils 0.9.18 package

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Please excuse my lack of knowledge and incorrect use of terminology.  I 
am looking to include irdadump in my build image within Yocto.

I modified the 
/poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/irda-utils/irda-utils_0.9.18.bb file to 
include irdadump in the list of targets to be built.

```
INITSCRIPT_NAME = "irattach"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "defaults 20"

TARGETS ??= "irattach irdaping irdadump"
do_compile () {
         for t in ${TARGETS}; do
                 oe_runmake -C $t
         done
}
```

However the bitbake process fails which comes down to the dependency of 
pkg-config and glib 2.0 required for idradump.

I did a quick search online and noticed that there was a separate .bb 
file for irdadump:
http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded/plain/recipes/irda-utils/

I tried to replicate this however was still faced with compiling issues.

Could anyone give me a helping hand on including irdadump to my 
irda-utils package?

Thank you

Comment: Using a separate recipe or taking the DEPENDS/CFLAGS/LDFLAGS  additions and using them in the existing recipe should work. "Compiling issues" is in my opinion a little too vague to help with

Comment: Oh, just realised: the pkgconfig dependency is wrong in the linked recipe: instead it should "inherit pkgconfig"

Answer (score 4):

To add irda-utils to your build image, just add IMAGE_INSTALL_append in your conf/local.conf file.Next time when you will run Bitbake,it will include irda-utlis package in your build image.

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " irda-utils"`